# Перезаписать значение объекта с помощью конструкции for in

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять, как на js перезаписать значение объекта с помощью конструкции **for in** ?

```
var Test = (function () {

    "use strict";

    var def = {
        test: '1',
        test2: '2'
    };

    function _run(data) {
        for (def in data) {
            /* ???? */
        }
     //результат
     console.log(def.test)
     // >> hi

    }

    return {
        run: function (data) {
            _run(data);
        }
    }

    }());

    Test.run({
        test: 'hi',
        test2: 'hi2'
    });
```

`Test.run();` - значения остаються дефолтными (def.test = 1, def.test2 = 2)

`Test.run({test: 'hi'});` - перезаписать только test, test2 оставить дефолтными.
`Test.tun({olala: 'hi'});` - выдать ошибку "нету такого параметра".

Comment: а что на выходе должно получиться?

Comment: Обновил свой вопрос

Comment: все равно непонятно. Нужно изменить значения в объекте `def`? а если в переданном объекте будут поля которых нет в объекте def?

Comment: Да все верно, если их нету, то выводить ошибку

Comment: в каком случае выводить ошибку? если передастся объект `{test:'hi'}` и `{test:'hi', test2:'hi', test3:'hi'}`, `{test:'hi', test3:'hi'}`?

Comment: Обновил совой вопрос

Comment: так а если есть и правильные свойства и неправильные? все равно ошибку бросать?

Comment: да Все верно =)

Comment: скажите словами обычно человека, что нужно? Есть объект что он имеет и что с ним должно быть в конце?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно проверить, чтобы `prop` (свойство `data`) был свойством в `def`, и если это так, то заменить значение этого свойства в `def`, иначе "выбросить" ошибку.

```
for (var prop in data) {
    if (def.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
         def[prop] = data[prop];
    } else {
        throw new Error(prop + ' isn\'t existing property');
    }
}
```

В вашем примере вы объект `def` (внутри `for-in`) затираете.

Comment: если в def какое-то из полей будет _undefined_ или 0 или false и т.д. код выкинет ошибку вместо присвоения

Comment: _если в def какое-то из полей будет undefined_ код выкинет ошибку вместо присвоения. `undefined` может быть вполне допустимым значением поля

Comment: @Grundy обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, помогло )